# Robot Framework : ${SPACE} behavior while using it from command line

Tags: python, cmd, robotframework

**${SPACE} Directly in Robot file:**

- ${space} is replaced as the exact space between two words. *Eg: "New${SPACE}user" -> "New user"*

but
**${SPACE} when we pass a value through cmd line**

- ${SPACE} is printing as same we send. it is not replacing as a space character.
  *Eg: "New${SPACE}Profile" -> "New${SPACE}Profile"*

so my question is,

What is the way to send a value through cmd line to make ${space} replaced to " "(space char)?

you can refer to the image.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried simply using a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line you must use command line processing rules. In this case, a single space is what you need to represent a single space. Because the command line uses spaces to separate arguments, you must quote the string so that the space is preserved.

Either of the following will work, and you can use either double quotes or single quotes as long as they are balanced:

```
robot -v 'cmdstring:New Profile' ...
robot -v cmdstring:'New Profile' ...
```

Another way if you're using a bash-like shell is to use the backslash to escape the space:

```
robot -v cmdstring:New\ Profile ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
My question is, I want ${SPACE} to be converted into space in the ROBOT file while we do it from the cmd line. It is the need for me to do it the same way! so how to do this @Bryan Oakley

Comment: @Sivabalakrishnan You can't use `${SPACE}` on the command line and expect it to be magically converted to a space in robot.

Comment: ok. I got the point. this cannot be done. we need to opt for another way. Thank you for the answers

Comment: @Sivabalakrishnan: it's not so much it _cannot_ be done, just that robot doesn't do it automatically. You can always convert a string with `${SPACE}` to a string with a space, but it's something you have to explicitly tell robot to do.